# Clifford correspondence(s) from Fong-Reynolds theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

The Fong-Reynolds theorem states a certain relationship between blocks of a normal subgroup $N\unlhd G$ and blocks of $G$, sometimes called the "Clifford correspondence for blocks". If one phrases this relationship in general enough terms using $G$-graded algebras and is a bit creative in its application, one can infer with relatively little effort both the classic Clifford correspondence for simple modules and the Clifford correspondence for indecomposable, $N$-relative projective modules.

I stumbled upon this a few months ago and I think I'm not the first to do so. Hence my question is: *Can anyone provide me with a reference for this relationship between the theorems?* I thought I had seen something similar to this in Dade's work, but I can't find it again. And maybe I'm misremembering and it wasn't Dade after all.

Comment: Dade certainly did a lot of work in this direction.

Comment: For example, see [https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970606?seq=1]

Comment: Also, Burkhard K\"ulshammer and I did some work on characters of relatively projective modules which made use of modules projective relative to a normal subgroup $N$ which may be viewed as a Clfford theory of such character rings (with module theoretiic ideas underlying). My paper was "On characters of relatively projective modules" and the successor with BK was "Characters of relatively projective modules II". Both appeared in JLMS around 1987.

Comment: (The successor was a joint paper with K\"ulshammer). Gabriel Navarro also did work in this direction when $N$ is a $p$-group.